# 興味を持っている vs 興味がある

Tags: word-choice, possession

Is there a difference between 興味を持っている and 興味がある? With physical objects I understand how the latter is more passive, but what about for abstract nouns like 興味? For example in the sentence

> 片岡さんは、外国語に**興味を持っている**から、フランス語でも中国語でも、すぐ覚えてしまう。

Is there any difference if I instead say

> 片岡さんは、外国語に**興味がある**から、フランス語でも中国語でも、すぐ覚えてしまう。

Comment: They're the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

興味を持っている is equivalent to "have an interest in sth."　興味がある is eqivalent to "be interested in sth." Both are saying the same thing.

Comment: Do Japanese feel that "興味を持つ" is a metaphor?

Comment: @konishiki. No. it isn't a metaphor. It's the same with "be interested in sth," just like the verb, 'interest' being used in the intransitive form.

Comment: Adding onto @Yoichi Oishi's comment, try to think 興味を持つ as something along the lines of "holding someones interest" or "hold attention"

Answer (score 2):

It's just my opinion,
I guess that a subject is different among those two sentences.

For example:

> 私は[疑問]{ぎもん}を持っている
> I have a question.
>
> 私は疑問がある
> →私(に)は疑問がある
> There is a question in my mind

The latter is a little bit more natural as spoken language in Japan than the former, but I think those are completely same.
I feel many of the former are expressions from the  literal translation.

> 私には[良]{よ}い[案]{あん}がある
> →I have a good idea.
> →私は良い案を持っている

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying "basically" the same, or "completely" the same"? "Basically" and "completely" are different.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. 
I revised my sentence. 
I am writing on the premise that this is only my opinion.